# I need some javascript condition like media query

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I want to add some condition in jquery like media queries in CSS, anyone can help me with this? I try the code below but is not working:

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        if (jQuery(window).width() >= 320) && (jQuery(window).width() <= 479) {

        }  

        if (jQuery(window).width() >= 480) && (jQuery(window).width() <= 567) {

        }  
    });
```

Comment: Open console F12 and check errors.

Comment: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '&&'

Comment: Right. `if (...) {}` in your case you have problems with parenthesis.

Comment: [Use the `matchMedia` API and reuse your media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia).

Comment: thank you but how can I use matchMedia in my case?

Comment: @zzzzBov That seems like overkill to deal with a simple syntax error.

Comment: @HoboSapiens, I posted it as a comment for a reason. It's a suggestion for a way of improving the code overall.

Comment: @zzzzBov: HoboSapiens is right, this is the right tool to use. It should be stated, that there is also an addListener method (and in case it is needed for IE9) a polyfill.

Comment: yes maybe it is right but how do I implement this?

Comment: @alexanderfarkas, did you get the names backwards?

Comment: here is the entire code jsfiddle.net/8tr7b2Ly

Comment: I have rolled back your question to its original version, which I have answered. Editing your question and including the fixes as you go renders the question and any existing answers nonsensical. If you need more help, open a new question on the new topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have parentheses around your individual conditions, but not around the `if` conditions as a whole.

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        alert("Running");
        alert(jQuery(window).width());
        if ((jQuery(window).width() >= 320) && (jQuery(window).width() <= 479)) {
            alert('Small screen');
        } else

        if ((jQuery(window).width() >= 480) && (jQuery(window).width() <= 567)) {
            alert('Large screen');
        }  else {
            alert("Biggest screen");
        }
});
```

Note the extra parentheses after `if` and before `{`

Comment: but when the screen is 1024? your code is running without conditions

Comment: It's because he has the else statement. If all the conditions fail i.e screen.width size... (Else) You have a big screen.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle to display the screen size, and I've changed the code here to match exactly.

Comment: thank you I've update my code like your code but still not working

Comment: @user4354004 are you not getting any alerts? If you are which one are you getting?

Comment: no i don't see anything only that the code is not working, I have there in code a small transition, but this is not working

Comment: Have you actually loaded the jQuery library in your page?

Comment: not working doesn't help us debug your problem. Please post ALL your code in a fiddle. @user4354004

Comment: You are not doing anything in the else statement @user4354004. If the screen sizes do not match it goes to the else statement.

Comment: I put there some code and now run only the code that is in the else { } even if my windows resolution is  >= 320

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need mediaqueries in JS to do your task the right way. First of all: how to work with media queries in JS. You can use `matchMedia`. Here is a [brief documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia).

Here is a simple example:

```
var smallMatcher = matchMedia('(max-width: 480px)');
var biggerMatcher = matchMedia('(max-width: 1024px)');

var run = function(){
    if(smallMatcher.matches) {
        //run code for small
    } else if(biggerMatcher.matches){
        //run code for bigger
    } else {
        //run code for else
    }
};

//now run it
run();

//in case you need to dynamically change on resize
//use addListener
smallMatcher.addListener(run);
biggerMatcher.addListener(run);
```

But as said, you don't need this. What you actually need to do is simple separation of concerns. Don't mix your behavior with your CSS. Simply add focus/blur or focusin/focusout events, the add or remove a class and do everything else in CSS.

This should result in clean and simple code, here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/po80g9hc/6/):

```
$('#searchbox')
    .on('focus', function(){
        $(this).closest('form').addClass('focused-field');
    })
    .on('blur', function(){
        $(this).closest('form').removeClass('focused-field');
    })
;
```

Everything else can and should be handled in CSS.

And In case you need the modify the style for the input button also if the button itself is focused and not only the search input you can see [the following fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/po80g9hc/4/).

Comment: thank you alexander but how can i make this with my animation?

Comment: my code in the if {} is this

   jQuery(search2).on('focus', function(){jQuery(icon2).animate({left: '-12px'}, 200, function(){});});
   jQuery(search2).on('blur', function(){if(search2.val() == '') {jQuery(icon2).animate({left: '195px'}, 200, function(){ });}});

can you make an example for me with this animation?

Comment: will be fine if I will make this animation with css, but I don;t know how to make my jquery to do that, do you have any idea?

Comment: is perfect thank you so much, I am beginner jquery, is there any way to put the button in the left and when you press on it to show and hide the input field? this is what I want :)